# how to use ssh as sock5 with curl in php?

Tags: php, curl

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($ip_ssh, 22);

if (ssh2_auth_password($connection,$username, $password)) {
    if ($tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, '127.0.0.1', 443)) {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ipinfo.io");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:443");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);   

        echo $result;
    } else {
        echo "Tunnel creation failed.\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "failed;
}
```

I tried but it did not work. Thank you for your interest .......................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the SSH tunnel as a SOCKS proxy with cURL since the tunnel doesn't represent a SOCKS connection.

The resource returned by [`ssh2_tunnel`](http://php.net/ssh2_tunnel) is a socket stream (like the one returned by [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/fsockopen)).

Even with a SOCKS proxy on the remote SSH server (e.g. [Tor](https://torproject.org)), I don't think there is a way to get cURL on the local server to go through the SOCKS proxy on the remote server over the tunnel with any combination of cURL proxy options.

Here is an example of using the tunnel:

```
<?php

$ip_ssh      = 'ssh_host';
$username    = 'user';
$password    = 'password';
$remote_host = 'ipinfo.io';

$connection = ssh2_connect($ip_ssh, 22);

$addr = gethostbyname($remote_host);

if (ssh2_auth_password($connection,$username, $password)) {
    if ($tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, $addr, 80)) {
        $request = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n" .
                   "Host: $remote_host\r\n" .
                   "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

        fwrite($tunnel, $request);

        $result = '';

        while (!feof($tunnel)) {
            $result .= fgets($tunnel);
        }

        echo $result;
    } else {
        echo "Tunnel creation failed.\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
Please take a look at this article :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25407332/3149852. His first method is similar to yours. I wouldn't like to use it for my reason. But I like his second idea. However, it didn't work. It failed at "socket_getsockname($localsock, $YourInternetIPaccessible, $openedPort);" 

Could you have any ideas to make it work?

Comment: I don't think that code works as expected or does what you want.  Why do you need to proxy cURL through the SSH tunnel?

Comment: because curl can use option CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE. It's quite difficult if I use your method.

Comment: With your method, how can I post data to https domains. For example: https://facebook.com ? Thanks.